# SQL Server 2008: find number of contiguous rows with equal values

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with multiple Ids. Each Id has values arranged by a sequential index.

```
create table myValues
(
  id  int,
  ind int,
  val int
)

insert into myValues
values
(21, 5, 300),
(21, 4, 310),
(21, 3, 300),
(21, 2, 300),
(21, 1, 345),
(21, 0, 300),
(22, 5, 300),
(22, 4, 300),
(22, 3, 300),
(22, 2, 300),
(22, 1, 395),
(22, 0, 300)
```

I am trying to find the number of consecutive values that are the same.

The value field represents some data that should be change on each entry (but need not be unique overall).

The problem is to find out when there are more than two consecutive rows with the same value (given the same id).

Thus I'm looking for an output like this:

```
id  ind   val   count
21  5     300   1
21  4     310   1
21  3     300   2
21  2     300   2
21  1     345   1
21  0     300   1
22  5     300   4
22  4     300   4
22  3     300   4
22  2     300   4
22  1     395   1
22  0     300   1
```

I'm aware this is similar to the island and gaps problem discussed [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/).

However, those solutions all hinge on the ability to use a partition statement with values that are supposed to be consecutively increasing.

A solution that generates the ranges of "islands" as an intermediary would work as well, e.g.

```
id  startind   endind
21  3          2
22  5          2
```

Note that there can be many islands for each id.

I'm sure there is a simple adaptation of the island solution, but for the life of me I can't think of it.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: i have tried to use a partition with row_number() over every combination of rows I could think of to get an index that resets on each different value, but that doesn't work without reordering.

Comment: The result you've said cant be done with your sample data..its imposiible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find the continuous group and then do a count() partition by that

```
select  id, ind, val, count(*) over (partition by id, val, grp)
from
(
    select  *, grp = dense_rank() over (partition by id, val order by ind) - ind
    from    myValues
) d
order by id, ind desc
```

Comment: Worked beautifully... Now I need to figure out how

Answer (score 0):

The other solution is obviously more elegant. I'll have to study it a little closer myself.

```
with agg(id, min_ind, max_ind, cnt) as (
    select id, min(ind), max(ind), count(*)
    from
        (
        select id, ind, val, sum(brk) over (partition by id order by ind desc) as grp
        from
            (
            select 
                id, ind, val,
                coalesce(sign(lag(ind) over (partition by id, val order by ind desc) - ind - 1), 1) as brk
            from myValues
            ) as d
        ) as d
    group by id, grp
)
select v.id, v.ind, v.val, a.cnt
from myValues v inner join agg a on a.id = v.id and v.ind between min_ind and max_ind
order by v.id, v.ind desc;
```